# Highlight a datagrid row in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I was wondering how to highlight a datagrid row in Flex depending on the value in one of the columns.

Example: One of the columns is ID. I would like to then highlight the row that matches a specific ID such as "1232".

Also is it possible to do this in datagrid? or do I have to use advancedDataGrid?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104754/842112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "highlight" you mean a visual change on how the row looks; I see two approaches.

You can select the row by setting the DataGrid's [selectedIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedIndex) or [selectedItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedItem) property, or select multiple rows by setting the DataGrid's [selectedIndices](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedIndices) or [selectedItems](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedItems) property.  This should cause the row to display the "selected" state; which can be specified with the selectionColor.

However, changing the selectedIndex / selectedItem could have undesirable side effects in certain circumstances.  For example, if you just want to change the color of a row to red because its total was below a certain threshold, that would be a different use case than actually selecting an item.  To do this, I would use a custom renderer that sets styles.  You may have to write a custom renderers for each column to make this work succesfully, though.